# Question clarification.

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise question:

"Let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does there exist a continuous injective function $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?"

What exactly does it mean?

Is the question: "Given an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, does there always exist a continuous injective function $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?"?
$$
\forall V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3:\ V \text{ is open } \Rightarrow \exists f:\ V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous and injective}
$$

Or is it maybe:
"Does there exist a continuous injective function $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$$
\exists f:\ V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous and injective}, V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3:\ V \text{ is open }
$$

I honestly do not have a clue.
How I would go about (dis)proving this would very much depend on my understanding.

Comment: Probably neither.  I'd modify the first one to say, "Given an open subset of R^3, when does there exist a ...."  The answer may be always, or never, or something in between.

Comment: You say "$V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$" twice, whereas $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. (And therefore there can _never_ exist such a function, if $V$ is non-empty.)

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I've corrected this to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: So you should consider the question "_Can_ there exist...?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement can be reformulated to

> Let $V\subset \mathbb R^3$ be open. *Under what circumstances* does there exist a continuous injective function $f:V\to\mathbb R$?

If you really want to make it formal, you can write

> Find a property $P$ such that
>   $$\forall V \subset \mathbb R^3 \text{ open}: P(V) \implies \exists f:V\to \mathbb R\text{ continuous and injective}$$

The answer would then be $P(V) := V = \emptyset$.

---

If $V$ is the empty set, there is such an $f$ (called the *empty* function).
It doesn't map anything and since $\mathrm{dom}(f) = \emptyset$, all statements about preimages of $f$ are vacuously true, hence $f$ is injective.

If $V$ isn't empty, it contains some open ball $B_\epsilon(x_0) \subset \mathbb R^3$. Since there is no injective map from $B_1(0)$ to $\mathbb R$ (and any $B_\epsilon(x_0)$), there cannot be an injective map from $V$ to $\mathbb R$.

Thus, the answer to the question is:

> If $V\subset \mathbb R^3$ is open, there exists a continuous function $f:V\to\mathbb R$ if and only if $V=\emptyset$.

Comment: Could you show me why there is no injective map from $B(0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Maybe a reference to a proof? In $\mathbb{R}$ it seems to be OK: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr

Comment: @SydKerckhove This is Borsuk-Ulam Theorem.

Comment: Well that seems to be far beyond the reach of an 'intro to analysis' student...

Comment: @SydKerckhove Unfortunately, your statement is basically equivalent to the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. Maybe you're only expected to state this without proof?

Comment: Definitely not. We're not even expected to have ever heard of that theorem.
I have found a proof at the level of an intro to analysis student: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321194/continuous-injective-function-from-open-part-of-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr

Comment: @SydKerckhove Nice. This is a proof of said theorem. By the way, you should have answered this here and not posted a duplicate question.

Comment: Acually, this question was about the formulation, not about the proof...

Comment: @SydKerckhove Sorry for that. I'll add an answer to this as well.

Comment: Your new edited answer is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following fact:

> There is no locally injective continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$.

Now, since $V$ is open, you can build a closed curve (for example, the equator of a sphere) inside some ball contained in $V$. This means that you are able to find some $\gamma: [0,1] \to V$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, which parametrizes your curve. You can suppose WLOG that $\gamma|_{[0,1)}$ is injective.

If $f: V \to \Bbb{R}$ is injective and continuous, then $f \circ \gamma$ is a locally injective continuous function and $f \circ \gamma(0) = f \circ \gamma(1)$: a contradiction.