# Continuous injective function from open part of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis

Let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but since I don't think there's anything special about $3$ in this case, let's say $\mathbb{R}^p$).
Prove that there can't exist a continuous injective function $f:\ V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Here's what I've tried:

Assume that there exists such a functien $f$.

- For every open $A \subseteq V:\ f(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$
- For every open $W \in \mathbb{R}:\ f^{-1}(W) $ is open in $V$ (definition of continuity).
- Because $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}:\ f(V) \rightarrow V$ can be regarded as a function and is a bijection.

I don't see how any of these can be a problem.

I can't even see a problem intuitively. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not somehow 'larger' than $\mathbb{R}$..

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate of [Question clarification.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321155/question-clarification/1321166?noredirect=1#comment2684364_1321166), as that question was about what a sentence meant, not about answerring it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question clarification.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321155/question-clarification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous injective function (with $p\ge 2$).

If $V$ is empty then there is no problem, there is a continuous injective function, the empty function.

If $V$ is non-empty, then there exists an open ball $B(x,\delta) \subseteq V$.
This open ball is convex and thus connected.
Because $f$ is continuous, the image of a connected set must be connected as well and must therefore be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $X$ be $B(x,\delta) \setminus \{x\}$. This is still connected ($p\ge 2$) so $f(X)$ must be an interval (connected) as well.
Because $f$ is injective:
$$ f(X) = B(x,\delta) \setminus f(\{x\} = f(B(x,\delta))) \setminus f(\{x\}) $$
... but this is not an interval. Contradiction.