# Prove: Any open interval has the same cardinality of $\Bbb R$ (without using trigonometric functions)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to prove that every open interval has the same cardinality of $\Bbb R$.

The question is:

Is it enough to prove that any open interval is uncountable? If I prove it, can I say that this interval has the same cardinality of reals?

I know that I can get a bijection using the tangent function, but I am not allowed to use trigonometric functions.

I've proved that $|(a,b)|=|(0,1)|$ so I may prove that $|(0,1)|=|\Bbb R|$ but I did not find the bijection without using trigonometric functions.

Comment: Several functions in the answer to this question avoid trigonometric functions: [Is there a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200180) You can have a look also at other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/200180).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the function

$$g(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$
Verify that $g$ is a bijection from real numbers to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

"Uncountable" just means "not countable", where countable is the smallest infinity. If you show that $(a,b)$ is uncountable, and that $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, you haven't shown that they have the same cardinality.

You *need* to exhibit a bijection. That is the very definition of "same cardinality". Any way you prove that the two have the same cardinality will, at least implicitly, exhibit a bijection.

"Same cardinality" *means* that there is a bijection. So you're asking if you can show that a bijection between these two sets, but without showing that there is a bijection between these two sets. You *have* to use a bijection. Any theorem, lemma, etc. **MUST** use bijections, as that is the very definition. What you're asking is like asking "can you show that 2 is even, without showing that 2 is even".

Edit, for an explicit bijection I leave the full construction to you (as it is somewhat tedious), but you could have something like:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-a} \text{ for } x\in (a,a+\mu/4)\\
\text{ linear connecting term for } x\in [a+\mu/4,a+3\mu/4]\\
\frac{1}{x-b} \text{ for } x\in (a+3\mu/4,b)
\end{cases}$$

where $\mu$ is the length of the interval.

Comment: Well, you can also exhibit an injection in both directions and apply Cantor–Bernstein.

Comment: My point really is that it's considerably easier to produce explicit injections compared to explicit bijections (between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ being an infamous example). The bijection that the proof of Cantor–Bernstein produces is pretty nonconstructive and nasty.

Comment: Well, I can use a bijection except using tan or another trigonometric function

Comment: Absolutely: I totally agree with you there.

Comment: @AlexTurner $\arg\tanh$?

Comment: If you're allowed to use bijections other than trig functions, what about the map $f(x)={1\over x}-1$ if $x>0$, $f(x)={1\over x}+1$ if $x<0$, and $f(0)=0$, applied to the interval $(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but there is one very simple bijection without trigonometric functions. Consider $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2x}  & 0<x<\frac 12 \\
\frac 1{2x-2} + 2, & \frac 12 \leq x < 1
\end{cases}$$

If you want $(a,b)$, it is, of course, simply a matter of scaling/shifting.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give another bijection, to add to the list (it has a geometric interpretation) :

$x\to \ln(\frac{1}{x-a} -\frac{1}{b-a})$ for $x\in ]a,b[$ is easily seen to be a bijection $]a,b[\to \Bbb{R}$

Comment: What does the interval(?) $]a,b[$ mean?

Comment: @Om3ga : sorry, this might be a french notatiom - it means the same as $(a,b)$, i.e. $[a,b]$ minus endpoints

Comment: ah ok, Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m$ is odd and $n$ is even. Then
$$ \frac{x^m}{1-x^n} $$
is a bijection $(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$. (It suffices to check it is increasing and unbounded in both directions: the former implies injectivity, the latter surjectivity.) The same applies to, for example,
$$ \log{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)} = 2\arg\tanh{x} $$

Comment: What's $\arg \tanh$?

Comment: Well, it's defined by that equation. It also happens to be the inverse of the function $ \tanh : \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the following answer to your post [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436940/give-a-biyection-f-c-d-to-bbb-r-f-no-trigonometric-to-prove-every-open) which was later marked as a duplicate of this question. As I take a different (and arguably more elementary) approach than the previous answers, I thought it might be a good idea to repost it for future reference:

---

You already know that there is a bijection $(c,d) \to (-1,1)$ and it thus suffices to find a bijection $f \colon (-1,1) \to \mathbb R$. The following will do:

For all $n \in \mathbb N_0$ we let $f \restriction_{[1- 2^{-n},1-2^{-n-1}]}$ be the linear function from $(1- 2^{-n} ; 2^n)$ to $(1-2^{-n-1} ; 2^{n+1})$ and likewise $f \restriction_{[-1+ 2^{-n-1},-1+2^{-n}]}$ is the linear function from $(-1+ 2^{-n-1} ; -2^{n+1})$ to $(-1+ 2^{-n} ; -2^{n})$.

The picture below demonstrates what's going on:

[image]