# Does there exist a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

We can find a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$. For example, we can use $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{1+|2x-1|}$ composed of parts of two hyperbolas, see the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282x-1%29%2F%281-abs%282x-1%29%29). Or we could appropriately scale the tangent function to get $g(x)=\tan\pi\left(x-\frac12\right)$, see the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28pi*%28x-1%2F2%29%29). Several such bijections are suggested in the answers to this post: [Is there a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr)

But does there exist a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?
If yes, then what is it?

Comment: Yes. What do you think?

Comment: Use the ideas in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) post.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote... For cardinality reason, the answer is obviously yes. The interesting part is "If yes, then what is it?"

Comment: So you're considering that it might be possible for $[0,1]$ to be "larger" than $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net some guys here are very fast with downvotes, but the interesting part is not that interesting, because Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein gives you a bijection, and it is a very familar example of how to construct a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ and the rest is made via compositions

Comment: @Domini Michaelis I agree, but if your don't have this background, which is probably the case of the OP writter, it is interesting to brainstorm on the topic.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yeah for sure, I think a comment that this is a duplicate and linking to an answered question would have been much better

Comment: @GitGud Maybe he's considering that they might be incomparable. It's not immediately obvious that you don't need AC for CBS.

Comment: @DRF As $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ I highly doubt they could be incomparable

Comment: @DominicMichaelis They can't, assuming you use classical logic (Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein). And they can't even in general I think since the bijection is actually strictly constructible. But it certainly is not right away obvious to a layman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s fix $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Define $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

- $g(0) = -1$
- $g(1) = 1$

and for $0<x<1$,

- if $f(x)\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then $g(x) = f(x)+1$
- if $-f(x)\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then $g(x) = f(x)-1$
- otherwise, $g(x) = f(x)$

Then, if $f$ is a bijection, so is $g$.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{N}^{*}$?