# Find a bijection between the set of real numbers and the interval $(−1, 1) ≡ \{\,x ∈ \Bbb R\mid − 1 < x < 1\,\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a bijection between the set of real numbers and the interval $(−1, 1) ≡ \{\,x ∈ \Bbb R\mid − 1 < x < 1\,\}$.

Hi am I trying to revise for an an exam and I came across this question which I can not figure out. I tried looking online but I kept just finding graphs.
Thank You

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find bijection map

$g:\mathbb{R} \to \left( { - 1,1} \right)$

Then, first write the any bijection map from $\mathbb{R}$ to any open interval.

And then make its range (co-domain) by some adjustment to required open interval.

Example:

$f\left( x \right) = {\tan ^{ - 1}}x$

then,

$\begin{gathered}
  Dom\left( f \right) = \mathbb{R} \\ 
  Range\left( f \right) = \left( { - \frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered} $

then, your job is to arrange your range (co-domain) as 
$\left( { - 1,1} \right)$

then, for this multiply your function f(x) by 
$\frac{2}{\pi }$,

$\frac{2}{\pi }f\left( x \right) = \frac{2}{\pi }{\tan ^{ - 1}}x$

then take,

$\begin{gathered}
  g\left( x \right) = \frac{2}{\pi }f\left( x \right) \\ 
   = \frac{2}{\pi }{\tan ^{ - 1}}x \\ 
\end{gathered} $

And then,

$\begin{gathered}
  Dom\left( g \right) = \mathbb{R} \\ 
  Range\left( g \right) = \frac{2}{\pi }\left( { - \frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) \\ 
   = \left( { - 1,1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Hence, the required bijection map $g:\mathbb{R} \to \left( { - 1,1} \right)$ is,

$g\left( x \right) = \frac{2}{\pi }{\tan ^{ - 1}}x$

I hope this will fulfill you required bijection map.

Answer (score 1):

How about $x\mapsto \frac x{|x|+1}$?

Comment: Where did you get that function from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use $tan^-{1}x$ function to define a bijection from $R$ to the interval$(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and then use linear map to construct explicit bijection

Comment: I will try that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function (e^x-1)/(e^x+1).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).