# How do I show a one-to-one correspondence between a line and a line segment?

Tags: set-theory, infinite-groups

Can it be done in the same way as we prove that the number of points on any two finite line segments are equal - geometrically?

Comment: I don't know how to visualize it geometrically, but the easiest function I can think of for this is $f:(0,1) \to (1,\infty)$ which is $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Are the segment closed? That is, do they include the end points?

Comment: *Hint*: you can start mapping $(0,1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ with $f(r)=\dfrac 1 r $.

Comment: You can see the post [is-there-a-bijective-map-from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr).

Comment: For an open segment (endpoints excluded), bend the segment into a semi-circle and project its points from the center  C of the circle onto a line not containing C . If one or both endpoints are included then a continuous bijection  is not possible, so use the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem.