# Given 2 functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g \circ f$ surjective. Show that $f$ does not need to be surjective.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

A friend has given me this task and asked for help. I immediately tried picking various $f$ and $g$ such that $g$ and $g\circ f$ are both surjective but $f$ is not. However, i always found myself restricting $\mathbb{R}$ to some subsets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ in order to make it work. I can't figure out how to prove it for

$$ \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{R}$$

Is it even possible? I also tried using sectionwise defined functions (different functions for $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$). However, no success.

Any advise? I'm starting to assume that it's not possible for $\mathbb{R}$ without any restrictions.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take, for instance,$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\leqslant-1\\x+3&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\text{ and }g(x)=x^3-3x.$$It is clear that $f$ is not surjective. However,$$g\bigl(f(\mathbb{R})\bigr)=g\bigl((-\infty,-1]\cup(2,+\infty)\bigr)=\mathbb R.$$

Comment: this is exactly what i needed! thank you very much :-) 
i couldnt get it done myself. highly appreciating your help.

Answer (score 1):

For all real numbers $x$ we have $\log(e^{x})=x$. Take $f(x)=e^{x}, g(x)=\log\, x$ if $x>0$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: that was exactly my very first approach. However, the domain of $\log(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$. I assume you've chosen $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = \ln(x)$, didnt you?

Comment: @Zest See my revised answer.

Comment: Regarding your revides answer: That was basically my second approach which i initially thought would solve it. But that results in $(f \circ g)(x)$ not being surjective, doesn't it?

Comment: @Zest Are you saying that the identity function $x \to x$ is not surjective?

Comment: for every negative $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $f(g(x)) = f(0) = e^0 = 1$.

for every positive $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you get $f(g(x)) = x$. 

so we have $(f \circ g)(x) = 1$ for all $x \le 0$ and $(f \circ g)(x) = x$ for all $x > 0$, i dont think this is surjective tbh. There is no $x$ such that $(f \circ g)(x) = -3$ for example.

Comment: @Zest Why  are you computing $f\circ g$? Don't you have $g\circ f$ in the question? Note that $g(f(-3))=g(e^{-3})=\log\, e^{-3}=-3$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was simply a typo. We are looking at $g \circ f$ indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
[image]

$g(x)=
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{1}{x} - 2  & x < \frac{1}{2} \\
      \ \frac{-1}{1-x} + 2 & x >= \frac{1}{2} \\
    \end{array} \}
\end{array}
$
[image]

and define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,1)$

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$
[Is there a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr)

$g o f$ is surjective but $f$ is not.