# How to visualize a bijection between a closed bounded interval and the real line?

Tags: real-analysis

I want a graphical interpretation of a bijection between a close bounded interval and the real line.Can someone give me a bijection not explicitly but graphically.

Comment: It's a lot easier to visualize a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$, rather than the entire number line. Would that be enough?

Comment: Tell me how to visualize that between [0,1] and (0,1).But it would not be enough for me because I want to visualize a bijection between [0,1] and R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps. The first is showing a bijection from an open interval to $\mathbb{R}$ and the second is to show a bijection from an open interval onto a closed interval.

A bijection from $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is given by $\tan(x)$.

For the second part: 
[How to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160738/587142)

EDIT: 
There are other options for the first bijection here:
[Is there a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200180/587142)

Comment: You did not get my question I think,I want a bijection that can be visualized I mean some diagram showing a one-one correspondence.